# Ember.js 1.10 - Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '"' is not a valid attribute name

Tags: javascript, ember.js

After upgrading from Ember.js 1.9 to 1.10 I got following error -

Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '"' is not a valid attribute name.

```
prototype.setAttribute = function(element, name, value) {
    element.setAttribute(name, String(value));
};
```

Values are:

```
value: "" 
name: """ 
element: <span></span>
```

What is easiest way to find what issue might be with the upgrade and what should be fixed? The error is not very user friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Steps to troubleshoot:

1. Open compiled template (in my case it was in stacktrace VM.js:XXXX).
2. Read it carefully.

In my case it contained

```
var el1 = dom.createElement("span");
dom.setAttribute(el1,"\"","");
dom.appendChild(el0, el1);
```

3. Open source template that corresponds these lines.

e.g.

```
<span {{action "setUrgency" urgentItem.urgency}} {{bind-attr class=urgentItem.styleClass}}"></span>
```

4. Remove ' (this was an issue).

This issue was caused by incorrect template (HTMLBars was able to compile it without warnings) however error occured during executing the compiled template. Once template is fixed, everything is working fine.

Comment: This should be added to your original question, not added as an answer.

Comment: This is a complete answer guys.

Comment: This error also occurs in Ember 2.7. It is basically complaining about malformed handlebars code.